# Regex not working in ProxyPassMatch regex apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an appache webserver which i am using for reverse proxy to apex ORDS server. I have the the below config in my file. My URL which users will be using is like this (apps.company.org). My requirement is when user types the url apps.company.org/repository this should take them to http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/repository/login. This is working fine as per my below config.
But whatever else they type after the / (ex- apps.company.org/sample) it should take them to another application which is http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/apps. I am trying to match the anything with regex in proxypassMatch as below in my config file. It is not working. I have tried Aloas match and rewriterule as well. None of them working. It errors with "Sorry this page is not found". Could anyone please help me on this

```
# forward dynamic (ORDS) requests to Tomcat
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  RequestHeader unset Origin
  ProxyPass /repository http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/repository/login
  ProxyPassReverse /investigator-repository http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/repository/login
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)  http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/apps
  ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*)  http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/apps 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Probably because you are not using the variable of the captured elements in the target. why regex there? why not just "ProxyPass / http://abc.cde.org:8080/ords/r/ws1/apps/" which will do the same you pretend with that